# Is there a way to put subheadings(for maps) in the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, memoir

In my thesis I am going to have a couple of maps and some pictures. All the files are image files so my plan was to enter them with the`\begin{figure}` coding. This means that they would all show up on the list of figures page. Due to the fact that it will not be a big list and should fit on one page what I am looking for is a way to identify what is a map and what is a picture and then put it in a subheading in the list of figures.

For example, an output like this;

> **List of Maps and Figures**
>
> ***Maps***
>
> Map 1 Map Caption
>
> Map 2 Map Caption
>
> ***Figures***
>
> Fig.1 Picture Caption
>
> Fig.2 Picture Caption

I would like to have all the number ordering like above, which I have already by using the `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`. Also I would just like the header and not the sub-heading to show up on the TOC.
I'm using the memoir class. I have not included a MWE as I have no idea how to create what I want. I was thinking maybe keywords in the same what I was able to split my .bib file but couldn't find anything for figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood you right, the following should do what you want. No matter if you are running `memoir`, `book` or `scrreprt` ;-)

The final composed list isn't a classical `listof` and don't recognizes KOMAs `listof-feature` nor `memoirs` `listof<...>*` feature. There will always be a toc-entry.

```
 \begin{filecontents}{lofigsandmaps.sty}
 \ProvidesPackage{lofigsandmaps}[2014/10/26 TeX.SX demo package]
 \usepackage{etoolbox}
 \newcommand{\listmapname}{List of Maps}
 \newcommand{\listoffigsandmapsname}{List of Figures and Maps}
 \newcommand{\figurepluralname}{Figures}
 \newcommand{\mappluralname}{Maps}
 \newcommand{\subtocfont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
 \@ifclassloaded{memoir}{%
  \newcommand{\mapname}{Map}
  \newfloat{map}{lom}{\mapname}
  \newlistof{listofmaps}{lom}{\listmapname}
  \newlistentry[chapter]{map}{lom}{0}
  \cftsetindents{map}{0em}{2.3em}
  \addtodef{\insertchapterspace}{%
  \addtocontents{lom}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
  }{}
  \newcommand{\listoffigsandmaps}{%
   \clearpage\markboth{\listoffigsandmapsname}{\listoffigsandmapsname}
   \chapter*{\listoffigsandmapsname}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoffigsandmapsname}
   {\subtocfont \figurepluralname\par\nobreak}
   \@starttoc{lof}
   \vskip 15\p@
   {\noindent\subtocfont \mappluralname\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}
   \@starttoc{lom}
  }
 }{%
  \usepackage{tocbasic}
  \DeclareNewTOC[type=map,
   float,
   listname=List of Maps,
  ]{lom}
  \let\l@map\l@figure
  \ifundef{\KOMAClassName}{%
   \newcommand{\listoffigsandmaps}{%
    \chapter*{\listoffigsandmapsname}
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase\listoffigsandmapsname}{\MakeUppercase\listoffigsandmapsname}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoffigsandmapsname}
    {\subtocfont \figurepluralname\par\nobreak}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \vskip 15\p@
    {\noindent\subtocfont \mappluralname\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}
    \@starttoc{lom}
   }
  }{%
   \newkomafont{subtoc}{\sffamily\Large}
   \newcommand{\listoffigsandmaps}{%
    \clearpage\markboth{\listoffigsandmapsname}{\listoffigsandmapsname}
    \addchap{\listoffigsandmapsname}
    {\usekomafont{subtoc} \figurepluralname\par\nobreak}
    \@starttoc{lof}
    \vskip 15\p@
    {\noindent\usekomafont{subtoc} \mappluralname\par\nobreak\vskip 10\p@}
    \@starttoc{lom}
   }
  }
 }
   \patchcmd{\@chapter}{\chaptermark{#1}}{%
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lom}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
   }{}{}
\endinput
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lofigsandmaps}
%\addtokomafont{subtoc}{\itshape}%If KOMA would be used
\addtodef{\subtocfont}{}{\itshape}%for memoir
%\renewcommand{\subtocfont}{\bfseries\Large\itshape}%for memoir or report
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigsandmaps
\listofmaps
\chapter{Treasure Island}
\begin{map}\caption{map to the lost treasure}
\end{map}
\blindtext[9]
\begin{figure}
    \caption{Long John Silver}
    \caption{The jolly Roger}
\end{figure}
\chapter{New York (NY) metro system}
\begin{figure}
    \caption[ A NYC metro train ]{the optional argument works
    as well}
\end{figure}
\begin{map}
    \caption{The NYC metro system}
    \caption{The metro system of Washington, D.C.}
\end{map}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A few more details in the question would have been nice, i decided some layout things on my own. You can amend it to your needs or ask for changes.

Comment: That works well. I may have to amend to meet some guidelines but it's generally what I was looking for. +1

Comment: Out of curiosity, did the package work *out of the box*? If you need help amending, let me/us know. We can certainly help.

Comment: Seemed to work straight away. I'll post a comment if I notice anything that needs amending.

Answer (score 2):

In `memoir` you can create a new environment that behaves like `figure` but has its own table of contents and numbering scheme.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\newcommand{\sator}{Sator arepo tenet opera rotas}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Tables}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{Figures}

\newcommand{\mapname}{Map}
\newcommand{\listmapname}{Maps}
\newlistof{listofmaps}{lom}{\listmapname}
\newfloat[chapter]{map}{lom}{\mapname}
\newlistentry{map}{lom}{0}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
\listoftables
\listoffigures
\listofmaps

\mainmatter
\chapter{Sator}

\begin{table}
\caption{\sator}
\label{tab:one}
    \fbox{\sator}\centering
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \fbox{\sator}\centering
\caption{\sator}
\label{fig:one}
\end{figure}

\begin{map}
\caption{\sator}
\label{map:one}
    \fbox{\sator}\centering
\end{map}

\chapter{Arepo}

\begin{table}
\caption{\sator}
\label{tab:another}
    \fbox{\sator}\centering
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
    \fbox{\sator}\centering
\caption{\sator}
\label{fig:another}
\end{figure}

\begin{map}
\caption{\sator}
\label{map:another}
    \fbox{\sator}\centering
\end{map}

\end{document}
```